# Internal iOS update server for iPads (any/all iOS)

Tags: ios, osx-server, network, software-update, mobile-device-management

Is it possible to setup an internal update server for iPads similar to the likes of OS X Server's update service (SUS)?

**Current issues:**

- Bandwidth concerns
- Do not want to jailbreak
- iOS updates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - both [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/) and the [Apple Configurator](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12) act as a single download point that can then apply one update over USB to an unlimited number of iOS devices.

No - iOS devices do not apply for OTA updates from any update server in an analogous manner to Lion's SUS.

It is notable that Mountain Lion is announces to not ship with a SUS and instead have updates arrive from the Mac App store - so Macs are becoming more like iOS rather than the other way which seems to be the foundational premise of your question.

Comment: I have read comments about Mountain Lion's decision and am disappointed by this. I am also aware of the USB syncing of iPads, unfortunately it is more of an overlay and less of an update. Also the fact that this is done 1 at a time in syncing stations is painfully slow, with high cost (syncing power stations) and inefficient as compared to SUS for Macintosh computers. Well I guess I better get used to this as you pointed out Mac OS is headed in the direction of Mac IOS. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Also thanks for the edit to my tags. MDM is definitely more appropriate. :)

Comment: Have you heard of any plans by Apple to address bandwidth issues in regards to OTA updates?

Comment: Apple is pretty open about few plans. Everything I can speak to gets included my answers. The good news is the updates can be delta updates so Apple clearly is aware of the impact to a corporate network when updates arrive simultaneously. Time will tell what they provide - I'm gearing up to support several clients as summer's changes arrive.